# Kafka Processor Context - schedule method not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are currently using the Kafka's Processor context #schedule method to assign a periodic task. However, the task fails to execute. Here is the code:

```
    @Override
  public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext) {
    store = (KeyValueStore<String, T>) processorContext.getStateStore(storeName);
    processorContext.schedule(Duration.ofHours(storeCleanupScheduledTaskIntervalHours), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, timestamp -> {
      LOGGER.info("Starting execution of task for deletion of obsolete records.");
      store.all().forEachRemaining(keyValue -> {
        if (isRecordExpired(keyValue.value)) {
          store.delete(keyValue.key);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

We deploy on a Linux server with the following distribution:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

The task is currently scheduled to execute every 6 hours. However, it does not start at all.
However, when the same method was deployed on another service with a slightly newer version of the CentOS(CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003), the task executed successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I find it unlikely the OS is causing this. Is NTP not running or your system clock otherwise skewed?

Comment: I checked and NTP is running.